# Reverse for 'employee-delete' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['employee/employee\\-list/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/delete/$']

Tags: jquery, django, ajax

I am getting `Reverse for 'employee-delete' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['employee/employee\\-list/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/delete/$']` this error when i try to delete an employee. I dont know why this error is giving. I have given correct url path.
I want to delete employee from my list table using ajax and jquery.

employee_list.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% load static %}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'employee/css/master.css' %}">

<div class="">
    <div class="table-wrapper">
      <div class="table-title">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h2><b>Employees</b></h2>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <a href="{% url 'employee:employee-add' %}" data-target="exampleModal" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal">
                            <span ></span>
                            <i class="material-icons"></i>
                            <span data-feather="plus"></span>Add New Employee
                        </a>
            <!--<a href="#deleteEmployeeModal" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal"><i class="material-icons">&#xE15C;</i> <span>Delete</span></a>-->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>
              <span class="custom-checkbox">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="selectAll">
                                <label for="selectAll"></label>
                        </span>
            </th>
                        <th>ID</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
                        <th>Department</th>
                        <th>Designation</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <!-- Loop for showing employee list in a table-->
          {% for employee in employees %}
          <tr>
            <td>
              <span class="custom-checkbox">
                  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" name="options[]" value="1">
                  <label for="checkbox1"></label>
                </span>
            </td>
                        <td>{{employee.e_id}}</td>
            <td>{{employee.first_name}}</td>
                        <td>{{employee.last_name}}</td>
            <td>{{employee.email}}</td>
            <td>{{employee.address}}</td>
            <td>{{employee.phone_number}}</td>
                        <td>{{employee.department}}</td>
                        <td>{{employee.designation}}</td>

            <td>
              <a href="{% url 'employee:employee-update' employee.id %}" class="edit" data-toggle="modal">
                                <i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit"></i>
                                <span data-feather="edit-2"></span>
                            </a>
              <a href="{% url 'employee:employee-delete' employee.id %}" id="btn" date-target="#deleteEmployeeModal" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');" class="delete" data-toggle="modal">
                                <i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete"></i>
                                <span data-feather="trash"></span>
                            </a>
            </td>
          </tr>
          {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
      </table>

            <div class="">
                {% if is_paginated %}
                <ul class="pagination">
                    {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
                        <li><a  href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}"><span data-feather="chevron-left"></span></a></li>
                    {% else %}
                        <li class="disabled"><span data-feather="chevron-left"></span></li>
                    {% endif %}
                    {% for i in paginator.page_range %}
                        {% if page_obj.number == i %}
                            <li class="active"><span class="pagination-number pagination-current">{{ i }} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span></li>
                        {% else %}
                            <li><a class="pagination-number" href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                    {% if page_obj.has_next %}
                        <li><a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}"><span data-feather="chevron-right"></span></a></li>
                    {% else %}
                        <li class="disabled"><span data-feather="chevron-right"></span></li>
                    {% endif %}
                </ul>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
    </div>

<div id="deleteEmployeeModal" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content"

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}

{% block scripts %}
    {{block.super}}

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.ajax("{% url 'employee:employee-delete' employee.id %}", {
        method: 'POST',
        success: function() {
            window.location.reload();
        },
    });

    </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
          // Select/Deselect checkboxes
          var checkbox = $('table tbody input[type="checkbox"]');
          $("#selectAll").click(function(){
            if(this.checked){
              checkbox.each(function(){
                this.checked = true;
              });
            } else{
              checkbox.each(function(){
                this.checked = false;
              });
            }
          });
          checkbox.click(function(){
            if(!this.checked){
              $("#selectAll").prop("checked", false);
            }
          });
    </script>

{% endblock scripts %}
```

I added script pointing to url 'employee:employee-delete' employee.id %
this is the urls.py file

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.urls import reverse
from . views import (
                    EmployeeListView,
                    EmployeeAddView,
                    EmployeeDetailView,
                    EmployeeUpdateView,
                    EmployeeDeleteView,
                    )

app_name = 'employee'

urlpatterns = [
    path('employee-list/', EmployeeListView.as_view(), name='employee-list'),
    path('employee-add/', EmployeeAddView.as_view(), name='employee-add'),
    path('employee-list/<int:id>/', EmployeeDetailView.as_view(), name='employee-detail'),
    path('employee-list/<int:id>/update/', EmployeeUpdateView.as_view(), name='employee-update'),
    path('employee-list/<int:id>/delete/', EmployeeDeleteView.as_view(), name='employee-delete'),
]
```

views.py:

```
class EmployeeDeleteView(DeleteView):
    """
    Deletes a created employee
    """
    template_name = 'employee/employee_list.html'
    model = Employee


    def get_object(self):
        id_ = self.kwargs.get("id")
        return get_object_or_404(Employee, id=id_)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        employee = self.get_object()
        return render(request, 'employee/employee_delete.html', {'employee': employee})

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('employee:employee-list')
```

Comment: In your JS you reference `employee.id` in a `url` tag but the variable `employee` does not exist I think as it is a list view - `{% url 'employee:employee-delete' employee.id %}`

Comment: so what should be the solution???